# Combine textwrap with changing one word colour in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I'm writing a text game in Python. I've written a function which takes a list of words and changes their colour, while leaving the rest white.

```
def highGreen(text, words):
    textWords = text.split(" ")
    highlight = set(textWords).intersection(words)
    for word in textWords:
        if word in highlight:
            print("\033[32m", end="")
            print(word, end=" ")
        else:
            print("\033[0m", end="")
            print(word, end=" ")
```

My problem is that I can't seem to combine this function with `textwrap.wrap` or `.fill`, so when printed onto the console words are broken in random places.

I've tried:

```
text = "This bed is super uncomfortable."
for line in textwrap.wrap(text, 80):
    highGreen(line, ["bed"])
```

but it still prints everything in one line.

The colouring is done in such a weird way because nothing else I tried worked in the Windows 10 console/PyCharm.

Comment: You are always ending your print with `end=" "`. This is never creating a new line, that is why everything shows up on the same line.

Comment: To fix this you either want to add an extra empty print statement somewhere to forcefully create a new line, or modify one of your `end`s to add a new line.

Comment: The `text` is less than 80 chars long !

Comment: @OMarMohamed this was just a sample text, the original is over 400 chars

Comment: OK. As @ZiyadEdher said, you need to print a newline character at the end of each `highGreen` call.

Comment: 2 additional notes, you don't need this line `highlight = set(textWords).intersection(words)`
and in case the last word is to be highlighted, you won't end the highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly,** your `text` isn't `80` characters long (in fact it's only `32`) so it would all fit on one line anyway.  Let's change that to `20` for this example.

**Secondly,** Your text *would* be broken up into `20` character chunks, you're just not printing any newlines.  `print()` usually adds them automatically but since you override that with the `end=` argument the new line is never printed.

We can fix this by adding a empty `print()` statement after you call `highGreen`.  (Remember, `print()` automatically prints a newline if you don't specify the `end=` arg)

**Example:**

```
text = "This bed is super uncomfortable."
for line in textwrap.wrap(text, 20):
    highGreen(line, ["bed"])
    print() # add this to print newline
```

**Output:**

```
This bed is super 
uncomfortable.
```

(The `bed` prints out green, I'm just not sure how to copy that into StackOverflow)

Answer (score -1):

`textwrap` is probably confused by the control codes (the result is the same even if the text is longer than the wrap value). You might want to try [`ansiwrap`](https://github.com/jonathaneunice/ansiwrap).

Comment: The ctrl codes are never passed into `textwrap`, they're added in the `highGreen` function which is called _after_ the text is broken up.

Comment: Right. It might still be better to construct the strings completely before printing any of them, instead of using print as a side effect inside the `highGreen` function.